# Second livewire wire:change method Not firing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

So i have this code, the getCustomers method on the first select works fine - the second one doesnt seem to fire off at all, its not even hitting the dd at the start of the method and im unsure why

Livewire code

```
public function getCustomers($PartnerId)
    {
        $team = Team::where('id', $PartnerId)->where('type', '=', 'Partner')->first();

        $this->customers = Team::where('team_id', $team->id)->where('type', '=', 'Customer')->get();

    }

    public function getProjects($customerId){
        $this->projects = Project::where('team_id', $customerId)->get();
    }
```

Blade template

```
<div class="col-span-4 sm:col-span-4">
                    <x-jet-label for="type" value="{{ __('Partner') }}" />
                    <x-select name="selectedPartner" wire:model="selectedPartner" wire:change="getCustomers(selectedPartner)">
                        <x-select-option :value="null">Select Option</x-select-option>
                        @foreach($partners as $option)
                            <x-select-option :value="$option->id" wire:key="{{$option->id}}">{{ $option->name }}</x-select-option>
                        @endforeach
                    </x-select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-span-4 sm:col-span-4">
                    <x-jet-label for="type" value="{{ __('Customer') }}" />
                    <x-select name="selectedCustomer" wire:model="selectedCustomer" wire:change="getProjects(selectedCustomer)">
                        <x-select-option :value="null">Select Option</x-select-option>
                        @foreach($customers as $option)
                            <x-select-option :value="$option->id" wire:key="{{$option->id}}">{{ $option->name }}</x-select-option>
                        @endforeach
                    </x-select>
                </div>
```

Solved this by wrapping each element in their own div tags as below

```
<div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-6">
    <div >
       <x-jet-label for="type" value="{{ __('Partner') }}" />
       <x-select name="selectedPartner" wire:model="selectedPartner" wire:change="getCustomers($event.target.value)">
       <x-select-option :value="null">Select Option</x-select-option>
           @foreach($partners as $option)
                <x-select-option :value="$option->id" wire:key="{{$option->id}}">{{ $option->name }}</x-select-option>
           @endforeach
       </x-select>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-6">
   <div>
      <x-jet-label for="type" value="{{ __('Customer') }}" />
      <x-select name="selectedCustomer" wire:model="selectedCustomer" wire:change="getProjects($event.target.value)">
      <x-select-option :value="null">Select Option</x-select-option>
      @foreach($customers as $option)
      <x-select-option :value="$option->id" wire:key="{{$option->id}}">{{ $option->name }}</x-select-option>
      @endforeach
      </x-select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution is dubious because even before the elements had their own  container: `<div class="col-span-4 sm:col-span-4">`. Remember to add a prefix for each wire:key to avoid conflicts in case of identical *ids* in the two different selects

Answer (score 0):

Add a different prefix in wire:key for each select, as the same *id* from different models causes conflicts: *wire:key* must be unique on the page
[Reference](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting#dom-diffing-cures)